# Large File Uploads Fails in Chrome with Valums

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, file-upload, filesize

I am using the valums ajax upload component (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). My site is going to have users uploading files that are greater than 500MB in size. I have a strict pure HTML requirement. I can successfully upload files of this size in Internet Explorer. However, when I attempt to use Chrome, the file is never written on the server, but only in the case of large files. For smaller files, the file is successfully written.  But for larger files, I get an "Maximum request length exceeded error".

Considering I can upload files of this size with IE, I know that the settings in my web.config are correct. This leads me to believe there is something in the XHR implementation that needs to be set to accommodate for files of this size. However, i'm not sure what that is. Can anyone provide a sample of values use with ASP.NET MVC that:

- Allows for large (>500 mb) file uploads in IE AND Chrome
- Shows the progress of an uploaded file in browsers that support XHR

Thank you so MUCH!

Comment: Are you seeing the "Maximum request length exceeded error" as a Yellow Screen Of Death?

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce your issue. Here's my setup in which I limited the files to 1GB.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(string qqfile)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var file = Path.Combine(path, qqfile);
        using (var output = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
            Request.InputStream.CopyTo(output);                
        }
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fileuploader.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="file-uploader">       
        <noscript>          
            <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        </noscript>         
    </div>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fileuploader.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
            action: '@Url.Action("upload")'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Things to notice in web.config is [`<httpRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

and if you are hosting this site in IIS7+ ([`<requestLimits>`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)) as well is required:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

With this setup I am able to upload files up to 1GB of size in the latest versions of FireFox 8.0, IE9 and Chrome 16.

I have hosted the site locally using IIS Express.