# MVC3 Large File-Uploader Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I use [Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to upload large files under MVC3 Razor.

Somehow It uploads only small files about 1Mb.

I already used web.config settings which should be good [Large File Uploads Fails in Chrome with Valums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871775/large-file-uploads-fails-in-chrome-with-valums)

But it doesn't help.

Here is my JS

```
 <script type="text/jscript">
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
            sizeLimit: 1024*1024*1024,  
            action: '/Test/UploadFile',
            multiple: false,
            onSubmit: function (id, filename) {
                this.params.param1 = $("#ImageTitle").val();
            },
            onProgress: function (id, fileName, loaded, total) {
                //  $('.qq-upload-list').hide();
            },
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                $('.qq-upload-list').hide();
                $("#ImageTitle").val("");
                genTable(responseJSON);
            }
        });

        function genTable(data) {
            var contentData = '';
            contentData += "<img class='myclass' src='/Test/Orders/thumb-" + data + "' />";
            $("#ImageList").html(contentData);
        }

        window.onload = createUploader;     
    </script>
```

Here is my web.config

```
<httpRuntime   
                 maxRequestLength="1024000"
                 requestLengthDiskThreshold="1024000"
                 executionTimeout="18000" 
                 />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons. First, your `maxRequestLength` attribute of the `httpRuntime`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(VS.71).aspx

has too small value. The runtime rejects too large requests and you just have to make this value larger.

However, the default request limit is around 4mb and you seem to be unable to post files larger than 1mb. It is possible then that your hosting provider imposes its own limits on the request size. If this is so, you'd have to negotiate  the limit directly with your provider.

Comment: Please have a look at my web.config I just updated the Question. Thank you!

Comment: The request limit is set in an explicit way in your `web.config`. Just increase the value (`maxRequestLength="1024000"`).

Comment: But I have maxRequestLength="1024000"  in web.config. And it still doesn't work

Comment: @Peretz: Read his answer one more time, he says "increase the value", not "use the value". 1024000 is 1 MB. Add a zero and you've got a 10 MB limit